# How to load separate component from a single build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yii

So The situation is I am writing a code for a legacy website that runs on **php yii framework**.

My Task is to make few components for that project some of them belongs to `PageA` and let say all the components for that page are loaded from `ContainerA` and  I have other page lets call it `PageB` which have few components and all that components are loaded from `ContainerB` now I have to create build for that project All those components are part of **single build**

My Question is How to load those components from their respective page from a **single build** with existing **framework routing**

**Edit:** I would appreciate a code sample to do so to get better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have multiple `ReactDOM.render` calls in the entry file of your build, and check if the container for a page exists in the document before rendering the component tree of that particular page.

**Example**

```
const pageOneContainer = document.getElementById('page-one-container');
if (pageOneContainer) {
  ReactDOM.render(<PageOneComponent />, pageOneContainer);
}

const pageTwoContainer = document.getElementById('page-two-container');
if (pageTwoContainer) {
  ReactDOM.render(<PageTwoComponent />, pageTwoContainer);
}
```